# Jade view not working possible due to line endings

Tags: unix, pug, line-endings

I wrote a file in jade on my Windows machine, pushed it to git then pulled it on my Linux machine. I think there might be something wrong with the line endings since no matter what I do with the file I get error:

> Line 111: Unexpected identifier
>      at throwError (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/lexical-scope/node_modules/astw/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1156:21)
>      at throwUnexpected (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/lexical-scope/node_modules/astw/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1199:13)
>      at expect (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/lexical-scope/node_modules/astw/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1222:13)
>      at parseGroupExpression (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/lexical-scope/node_modules/astw/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1492:9)
>      at parsePrimaryExpression (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/lexical-scope/node_modules/astw/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1552:20)
>      at parseLeftHandSideExpressionAllowCall (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/lexical-scope/node_modules/astw/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1636:61)
>      at parsePostfixExpression (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/lexical-scope/node_modules/astw/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1695:20)
>      at parseUnaryExpression (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/lexical-scope/node_modules/astw/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1775:16)
>      at parseMultiplicativeExpression (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/lexical-scope/node_modules/astw/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1781:20)
>      at parseAdditiveExpression (/usr/lib/node_modules/jade/node_modules/with/node_modules/lexical-scope/node_modules/astw/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1798:20)

The currernt file is just

> extends layout

and I still get the error. Is the problem the line endings or something else. I'm using latest version of jade. (0.35.0)

Comment: Yes, Windows to Linux ports can suffer from end of line character issues. Have you tried copying just the text without the end-of-line characters into a new file and seeing if that works? You can also use a program to convert the eol characters. Here are a couple options for doing that: http://kb.iu.edu/data/acux.html.

Comment: @user1334007, I checked outt hese tools. Thanks. They'll probably be useful sometime. Just so others know, I don't think the problem was with the git or Unix/Windows line endings. I think I had a problem with my local jade configuration. I removed the repository, cloned it again and did a fresh npm install of jade an all other dependencies and it worked fine.